# How can I modify a custom xml node

Tags: c#, xml

I have an xml file which was built up from blocks like this:

```
<BasicOptions id="OwnCrypt">
    <Font>Angsana New</Font>
    <FontColor>Aquamarine</FontColor>
    <FontSize>12</FontSize>
    <FontStyle>Normál</FontStyle>
    <BackgroundImage>Cryptonite\System\Resources\Media\Pics\grumpy.jpg</BackgroundImage>
    <ImageResolution>1280 X 1024</ImageResolution>
    <FormSize>1280 X 1024</FormSize>
    <FormPosition>CenterParent</FormPosition>
    <Opacity>70</Opacity>
</BasicOptions>
```

I made six of these blocks in a root element( named Options). I have some problem with the
`<FormSize>` node, because from the options form it can get empty value( which means I don't change it's resolution), and then I would like to set the `<FormSize>` node's value to the basic resolutions of the forms.
Here is the updater button event( if it helps anything):

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            boxes[0] = checkBox1;
            boxes[1] = checkBox2;
            boxes[2] = checkBox3;
            boxes[3] = checkBox4;
            boxes[4] = checkBox5;
            boxes[5] = checkBox6;
            ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
            ArrayList bl = new ArrayList();
            foreach (CheckBox cb in boxes)
            {
                if (cb.Checked)
                    al.Add(cb.Text);
            }
            if(comboBox1.Text=="")//Betűtípus
            {
                bl.Add("Times New Roman");
            }
            else
                bl.Add(comboBox1.Text);
            if (comboBox2.Text == "")//Betűszín
            {
                bl.Add("Fekete");
            }
            else
                bl.Add(comboBox2.Text);
            bl.Add(numericUpDown1.Value.ToString());//Betűméret
            if (comboBox3.Text == "")//Betűstílus
            {
                bl.Add("Normál");
            }
            else
                bl.Add(comboBox3.Text);
            if (comboBox4.Text == "")//háttérkép
            {
                bl.Add(@"Cryptonite\System\Resources\Media\Pics\grumpy.jpg");
            }
            else
                bl.Add(comboBox4.Text);
            if (comboBox5.Text == "")//háttérkép felbont
            {
                Xml.resRequest(al);
            }
            else
                bl.Add(comboBox5.Text);
            if (comboBox6.Text == "")//felbontás
            {
                Xml.resRequest(al);
            }
            else
                bl.Add(comboBox6.Text);
            if (comboBox7.Text == "")
            {
                bl.Add("WindowsDefault");
            }
            else
                bl.Add(comboBox7.Text);
            bl.Add(numericUpDown2.Value.ToString());
            Xml.Writer(al, bl);
            al.Clear();
            bl.Clear();
        }
```

It has an order to get the values and give to the updater method, but if anybody has a better idea, that makes me very happy. :)

Comment: so what problem are you actually having.. what happens if the fontsize has no value..does this affect the screen resolution>? if so sounds like you would need to create a static default value to use if the fontsize happens to be empty

Comment: If it's empty, then the forms don't get their w and h values. if that means that they will have the basic resolution which has been set in the visual studio, then I have no problem.

Comment: Then can you clarify what the actual problem is since you stated something about `<FormSize>`?

Comment: I was feared that if it's empty, it will cause exception, but now I see, then it sets the basic values. Now the question is: If I add the xml a String.Empty value, will that change anything or not?   And sorry for my english skills:( Here's the time about 10pm, andI'm really tired)

Comment: try testing it with `string.Empty` to see what happens.. perhaps you should sleep on it..it's not good to code with a tired mind.. you may be over thinking the obvious..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a DTO object to store the values and use one of the built in serializers to form the xml. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx

The DTO class would have properties that you could use to detect if the value needs to be set to the default.

```
public class Foo {
  private string _bar;
  public string Bar 
  {
    get { return String.IsNullOrEmpty(_bar) ? _bar = "default value" : _bar; }
    set { _bar = value; }
  } 
}
```

Rather then populating the ArrayList, populate the DTO.